# ITunes Apple Store rating is different in mobile and web

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

We have uploaded Application on iTunes for 1 and half years. It is showing different ratings on iOS mobile Store and on Web Store. What is the reason for this different ratings and what is the fixation for this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image: web itunes store image is attached below]

[image: Mobile App store screenshot.]

Answer (score 2):

The displayed rating in the App Store depends on the region.

So the app's web page region is probably different from the App Store region on your iPhone.

To check the ratings of all regions, visit the info page of your app in App Store Connect.